# How to add 1 million rows of dataframe to .xlasx? Chunks approach is not working

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I had read the CSV of 10 GB with chunks logic and store it in DataFrame. Now I want to write that in Excel file(.xlsx).

Chunks logic I have tried but didn't work at all.

I Have tried this but didn't work

```
n = 100000 

list_df = [data[i:i+n] for i in range(0,data.shape[0],n)]

fn = 'OUTPUT\PythonExport.xlsx'
count = 0

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn)

for df_chunk in list_df:
    df_chunk.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=(count==0), startrow=count+(count!=0))
    count += len(list_df)

writer.save()
```

Comment: 10 GB excel file? What's the point?

Comment: *It doesn't work* means nothing. Please describe what happens and in case of an error the exact error message and the stacktrace.